# how can convert mp3 to ogg by php?

Tags: php, audio, converters

I'm using windows 7 and xampp in localhost.I want to convert mp3 audio into ogg audio by php script.I downloaded 'ffmpegConverter_v0.2' zip file where the folder structure is :

```
ffmpegConverter_v0.2
  --consoleConversor
      --consoleConversor
      --consoleConversor.exe
      --ffmpeg.dll

  --consoleMonitor
      --consoleMonitor
      --consoleMonitor.exe
      --ffmpeg.dll
      --Queue.xml

  --serviceConversor
      --ffmpeg.dll
      --serviceConversor
      --serviceConversor.exe

  --serviceMonitor
      --ffmpeg.dll
      --Queue.xml
      --serviceMonitor
      --serviceMonitor.exe

  --LEEME.txt
  --README.txt
```

I keep the 'ffmpegConverter_v0.2' folder,mp.php and 'a.mp3' in same folder and used the following code in mp.php:

```
<?php    
exec("ffmpegConverter_v0.2\serviceConversor\serviceConversor.exe -i a.mp3 -acodec libvorbis ap.ogg");
?>
```

then got the following error message :
[image]

what wrong did I do ? whats the exact way to install ffmpeg ? whats the exact way to write the command in php script for that and how can that be used in online server ? is there any other better converter else ?

-Thanks.

***EDIT:***

when I used the following line

```
<?php
 exec("ffmpegConverter_v0.2\consoleConversor\consoleConversor.exe -i a.mp3 -acodec libvorbis ap.ogg");
?>
```

then I got this message
[image]

I also tried this :

```
<?php   
exec("c:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\InstallUtil.exe serviceConversor.exe"); 
exec("ffmpegConverter_v0.2\serviceConversor\serviceConversor.exe -i a.mp3 -vcodec libtheora -acodec libvorbis ap.ogg");
?>
```

then got the same message like the first picture.

Comment: This has absolutely NOTHING to do with php. Go read the FFMPEG docs... Tip: perhaps the word "service" in the .exe's file name should be a clue as to why you're getting that error.

Comment: so my php code is ok ? and did I download the right zip file ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Forget about that `serviceConversor` thing.

Get an [FFmpeg build for Windows](http://ffmpeg.zeranoe.com/builds/) (a static build that matches your architecture should be a good start to avoid other DLL/etc. problems).

Then use `exec`:

```
<?php
    $retCode = exec('C:\\path\\to\\ffmpeg.exe -y -i file.mp3 -acodec libvorbis file.ogg');
?>
```

Don't forget to escape the backslashes (`\\`); you didn't in your question.

`exec` will return the return code of FFmpeg (I put it in `$retCode` here), which is 0 for a success.

As some noted, you can add the `-aq` option to set the OGG output quality for a VBR transcoding.

libvorbis is built in the static FFmpeg version; I just checked using `ffmpeg.exe -codecs`:

```
DEA.L. vorbis               Vorbis (decoders: vorbis libvorbis )
```

where DE means decoding and encoding are supported for this codec.

Comment: let me try that.I'm downloading "32-bit static builds" from that link.

Comment: If you're actually running a 64-bit Windows, I strongly suggest the 64-bit build as it should be more performant in this case.

Comment: mine is 32-bit windows so I downloaded 32-bit static.and my code was >> <?php $retCode =exec('."\"\ffmpeg"\"\bin"\"\ffmpeg.exe -y -i am.mp3 -acodec libvorbis apm.ogg'); ?> // I kept mp.php and 'ffmpeg' folder in same folder 'mp3'.

Answer (score 2):

One of these should work:

```
ffmpeg -y -i a.mp3 -acodec libvorbis -aq 50 output.ogg
ffmpeg -i 1.mp4 -vcodec libtheora -acodec libvorbis testjohn4545454.ogg
```

Comment: I tried both lines // exec("ffmpeg\serviceConversor\serviceConversor.exe -y -i a.mp3 -acodec libvorbis -aq 50 output.ogg");
exec("ffmpeg\serviceConversor\serviceConversor -i a.mp3 -vcodec libtheora -acodec libvorbis testjohn4545454.ogg"); (changed the folder name from 'ffmpegConverter_v0.2' to 'ffmpeg') but got the same error message. did I write the code correctly ?

Answer (score 2):

execute this in it's own process and in the background, otherwise your PHP script will hang whilst waiting for the conversion to complete.

The code:

```
passthru("/usr/local/bin/ffmpeg -i 1.mp4 -vcodec libtheora -acodec libvorbistestjohn4545454.ogg 1> /path/to/logfile.txt 2>&1 &");
```

Comment: Clearly the OP is not using a UNIX box... I doubt `/usr/local/bin/ffmpeg` will be found.

Answer (score 1):

The best advise I can give you:

> If there is a README file, and something is not working. Read it!

That being said, you are trying to run a command against `serviceConversor.exe`. That will not work as this is a windows service and it needs to be installed first. There is also another file called `consoleConverser.exe` and, as the README file says, 'Can be executed without previous installation.'.

I'm assuming that you already have [ffmpeg](http://www.ffmpeg.org/) installed as that is required

So your first option would be to try and execute the right command like. Keep in mind that I'm not familiar with this conversor, so I have no idea if this is the right command. I'm here to help with the error message.

```
<?php    
exec("ffmpegConverter_v0.2\consoleConversor\consoleConversor.exe -i a.mp3 -acodec libvorbis ap.ogg");
?>
```

Now if this fails you can still try the second part of the readme. Which is to install the windows service. This has to be done manually, which is explained [in the ms knowledgebase](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sd8zc8ha%28v=vs.80%29.aspx).

> Unfortunately the serviceConversor has only been tested with Windows XP and I can not install it on my Windows 7 system, but perhaps you have more luck.

Now this says you can directly call `installutil serviceConversor.exe` when you are in the `ffmpegConverter_v0.2\serviceConversor\` folder using `cmd`, but chances are you will get a message saying that installutil could not be found. In that case you can run it with the full path, which is normally one of these, depending on your .NET version and if you are running window 7 32 or 64.

```
c:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\InstallUtil.exe
c:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\InstallUtil.exe
c:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v2.0.50727\InstallUtil.exe
c:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\InstallUtil.exe
```

So in my case, the full command would be (from the serviceConversor folder)

```
c:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\InstallUtil.exe serviceConversor.exe
```

Comment: Your errors have nothing to do with php.Stop using it untill you get the convertor running. Use winkey+R and type `cmd` and hit entrer. Type your commands there to get output. Also you do have ffmpeg installed?

Comment: which command should I type in command window ? I tried "c:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\InstallUtil.exe serviceConversor.exe". is it ok ? (I kept 'ffmpegConverter_v0.2' folder in 'mp3' folder where mp.php is kept in htdocs)

Comment: The command window is basically the same as the `exec` function. Only you get direct output. So you can use it to try out which command on ffmpeg convertor works. I have never used it, so I cannot help you there

Comment: I tried "ffmpegConverter_v0.2\serviceConversor\serviceConversor.exe -i a.mp3 -vcodec libtheora -acodec libvorbis ap.ogg" in cmd but got same message like 1st picture.is there any other good converter else than ffmpeg ?

Answer (score 1):

MP3->OGG

```
ffmpeg -i input.mp3 -ab 6400 output.ogg
```

OGGDEC.EXE
OGG->MP3

```
OGGDEC.EXE myfile.ogg --stdout | LAME.EXE -V5 --vbr-new - myfile.mp3
```